# Insert Multiple Images into a Image column in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to insert multiple images into a `Image` datatype column in `sql server 2012`.

The folder has multiple `.jpg` and `.png` files.

I am currently using this sql to `insert` one by one

How can I insert multiple images or the whole folder thanks.

```
INSERT INTO Images(ImageId, ItemId, Caption, Image)
Values(NEWID(), null, null,(  
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(
   BULK 'C:\Images\image004.jpg',
   SINGLE_BLOB) AS x))
```

Here is the table with clustered index on the ClusterKey column

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Images](
    [ImageId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [ItemId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [Caption] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Image] [image] NOT NULL,
    [ClusteredKey] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Images] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [ImageId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Currently Trying this approach

```
--Table to process the files

CREATE TABLE imagelist 
  ( 
     imgfilename VARCHAR(200) 
  ) 
GO 
--Put all file name in a table for easy processing

DECLARE @SQL AS NVARCHAR(2000) 
SET @SQL =N'xp_cmdshell ''dir c:\Images /B''' 
INSERT INTO imagelist (imgfilename) EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
GO
--Import data into target table

DECLARE @SQL AS NVARCHAR(2000) 
DECLARE @ImgFilename AS VARCHAR(200) 
DECLARE filelist CURSOR FOR 
  SELECT imgfilename 
  FROM   imagelist 

OPEN filelist 

FETCH next FROM filelist INTO @ImgFilename 

WHILE ( @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 ) 
  BEGIN 
      SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO Images(ImageId, Image)   Values(NEWID(),( select  reverse(substring(REVERSE(''' 
                 + @ImgFilename 
                 + ''') ,charindex(''.'',REVERSE(''' 
                 + @ImgFilename + ''' ),1)+1,LEN(''' 
                 + @ImgFilename 
                 + '''))) , (SELECT img.bulkcolumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''c:\Images\' 
                 + @ImgFilename + ''',SINGLE_BLOB) AS img))' 

      EXEC Sp_executesql 
        @SQL 

      FETCH next FROM filelist INTO @ImgFilename 
  END 

CLOSE filelist 

DEALLOCATE filelist
```

Comment: From whence do you obtain the file names?  Are they in a table?

Comment: Stored locally in a images folder. The names can be image001.jpg, image002.png, image003.jpg etc. in the folder.

Comment: incorrect syntax near 'INSERT INTO Images(ImageId, Image)   Values(NEWID(),( select

Comment: You tell SQL Server that you'll insert `ImageId` and `Image`, then you insert a GUID, a filename (without type) and the contents of the file.  Three columns of data into two table columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows one way to import multiple files where the filenames can be calculated:

```
declare @Count as Int = 3622;
declare @Filename as VarChar(128);
declare @Statement as VarChar(256)

while @Count <= 3625
  begin
  set @Filename = 'C:\Photos\IMG_' + Right( '000' + Cast( @Count as VarChar(5) ), 4 ) + '.JPG';
  set @Statement = 'select * from OpenRowSet( Bulk ''' + @Filename + ''', Single_Blob ) as Nought';
  execute( @Statement )
  set @Count = @Count + 1;
  end;
```

Not pretty, but if this is a one-time import then it may not matter.